Vertex AI authentication failed with service account credentials
I am developing a server application in TypeScript that uses the text generation feature of Vertex AI. The application is built as a Docker image and runs on an on-premises Kubernetes (K8S) cluster.
When the application runs in the K8S cluster, it fails to call Vertex AI methods, returning the following error:
[ExceptionsHandler] [VertexAI.GoogleAuthError]: Unable to authenticate your request
...

Here are the steps I took for authentication:

I authenticated with
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.


This works fine on my local Linux machine, but fails in the K8S cluster.
The runtime environment differs between my local machine and the K8S cluster. On my local machine, there are no restrictions, but the K8S environment has some constraints. For example, the first problem I encountered was credential errors due to custom credentials. To address this, I registered the PEM file in the service accounts of the IAM & Admin page in the Google Cloud Console, and then ran:
gcloud config set custom_ca_certs_file=custom_cert.pem

After this, the command gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS succeeded. Despite this, the Vertex AI method calls still fail in the application running on the K8S cluster.


Here are additional details:

The service account key file is correctly set in the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
The Docker image has the necessary tools and credentials to authenticate with Google Cloud.
The service account has the required permissions for Vertex AI.

What additional steps can I take to resolve this authentication issue in the Kubernetes cluster?

I encountered this issue and managed to resolve it. Here’s what worked for me:
I found out there was an environment variable that I should set for the custom certificate for Node.js:
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/custom_cert.pem

After setting this, it works.
